# How do I prevent a product from being added to the cart?

Tags: commerce

A common question I hear is "How can I prevent a product from being added to the cart?" There are several reasons why you'd want to do this, most end up being related to some logic being required to determine if a product is eligible without actually deactivating the Add to Cart button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you probably ought to actually disable the Add to Cart button, you'd actually put logic for determining whether or not a product should be added to the cart in a validate handler.

The first step us to add a `form_alter` hook that adds a validation handler to the add to cart forms.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add a validate hook so that the order can be checked to ensure that the
  // our constraints are met.
  array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'MYMODULE_validate_some_stuff');
}
```

*Note: this works because of [`commerce_cart_forms()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_forms/7) which adds the generic form callback instead of requiring us to look for the string in the `$form_id`.*

Now, you just need to implement your logic:

```
/*
 * Check the product/order against my constraints.
 */
function MYMODULE_validate_some_stuff(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($form_state['values']['uid']);
  $line_item = $form_state['line_item'];

  if (/* your logic here */) {
    form_set_error('product_id', t('Sorry, you can\'t do that!'));
  }
}
```

You'll notice that the `commerce_order` is loaded by the user's UID and you've got access to the `commerce_line_item` that you can then use to grab the product (use `$line_item->commerce_product`). Also, there is no need to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Just set an error.